# Count 'HAVING' where all records have column = ''

Tags: mysql, count, having

Here is my query...I am trying to find all BLNUMBERS that have more than one CONTAINER where all containers' status = ''. Why would this not work? I'm currently getting some BLNUMBERS where all containers' status = '' but also some where status <>''. EDIT: How can I find BLNUMBERS where some containers' status ='' and some container' status <> ''

```
 SELECT
     DISTINCT
     BLNUMBER
     #,CONTAINERNUMBER
     ,COUNT(CONTAINERNUMBER) AS COUNT
 FROM   
     SHIPMENTS
 WHERE
      BLNUMBER <> ''
      AND CDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND CDATE < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
      AND CONTAINERNUMBER <> ''
      AND CONTAINERNUMBER NOT LIKE '.AIR%'
      AND CONTAINERNUMBER NOT LIKE 'AIR%'
      AND CARRIER_ID <>8
      AND STATUS = ''
  GROUP BY 
      BLNUMBER
  HAVING
      COUNT > 1
```

Comment: is `BLNUMBER` supposed to be unique? if so, why are you dong `SELECT DISTINCT`? If not, then just having a `BLNUMBER` does *not* guarantee a unique record.

Comment: It's not supposed to be unique. This table can have multiple 'containers' per 'blnumber.' The uniqueness is an ID. (I didn't design this table)

Comment: understood, so then, if you are only selecting `BLNUMBER`s and a `count` in the above query, how do you know if you have one with a bad status, since just a `BLNUMBER` is not enough to identify a unique record?

Comment: I only want to see one BLnumber where every container listed with that BLnumber has a status = ''

Comment: be careful of `null` fields. If your fields (`BLNUMBER`, `STATUS`, `CONTAINERNUMBER`) can be nullable, use the null-safe comparator `<=>` instead of `=`

Comment: All are constrained to Not Null, but thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand this correctly, you want to select all `BLNUMBERS` for which every `CONTAINER` of that `BLNUMBER` has a blank `STATUS`, meaning you want to exclude `BLNUMBERS` that have at least 1 `CONTAINER` with a non-blank `STATUS`?

So to do that, I would count the total number of `CONTAINER`s per `BLNUMBER`, and then count the total number of `CONTAINER`s with a blank `STATUS` per `BLNUMBER`, and then only return the `BLNUMBERS` that have the number of total `CONTAINER`s equal to the number of blank `CONTAINER`s.

So

```
SELECT 
  totalBlanks.BLNUMBER,
  totalBlanks.`count` 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    BLNUMBER,
    COUNT(*) `count` 
  FROM
    SHIPMENTS
  GROUP BY BLNUMBER) totals 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      BLNUMBER,
      COUNT(*) `count` 
    FROM
      SHIPMENTS 
    WHERE `STATUS` = '' 
    GROUP BY BLNUMBER) totalBlanks 
    ON totals.BLNUMBER = totalBlanks.BLNUMBER 
WHERE totals.`count` = totalBlanks.`count`
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm looking into this. But, this shows me every BLnumber even if it only has one record in the table, with one container. I need BLnumbers that have more than one different container number.

Comment: Alright, I just added 'having count > 1' after the second 'GROUP BY.' Going over results right now.

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you sir! I'll work on finding where some status = '' and some status <>'' (per BLnumber) and let you, and anyone following know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The following query gets all `BLNUMBER`s that have any container with no statuses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BLNUMBER
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE BLNUMBER <> '' AND
      CDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND
      CDATE < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND
      CONTAINERNUMBER <> '' AND
      CONTAINERNUMBER NOT LIKE '.AIR%' AND
      CONTAINERNUMBER NOT LIKE 'AIR%' AND
      CARRIER_ID <> 8 
GROUP BY BLNUMBER, CONTAINERNUMBER
HAVING MAX(STATUS) > '';
```

To get the ones that have multiple containers requires an extra level of subquery:

```
SELECT BLNUMBER
FROM (SELECT BLNUMBER, CONTAINERNUMBER
      FROM SHIPMENTS
      WHERE BLNUMBER <> '' AND
            CDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND
            CDATE < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND
            CONTAINERNUMBER <> '' AND
            CONTAINERNUMBER NOT LIKE '.AIR%' AND
            CONTAINERNUMBER NOT LIKE 'AIR%' AND
            CARRIER_ID <> 8 
      GROUP BY BLNUMBER, CONTAINERNUMBER
      HAVING MAX(STATUS) > ''
     ) b
GROUP BY BLNUMBER
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Yes, that gives BL that have multiple containers 'assigned, but seeming all with a status. Right now I'm working on BL's that have multiple containers, where some containers have any status, AND some containers have none (default = '' for status in this table). I'm trying to alter the original query you posted to meet this requirement. I'm about to post what I came up with..

Comment: @user3242558 . . . If you have a different question, you should post it as a separate question, rather than in a comment or by changing a question in such a way that answers are invalidated.